# Como cambiar de vistas entre el nav_header_main y una actividad empty, android

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, activity, navigation-drawer

pasa que estoy haciendo una app con java y estoy algo complicado... les explico, tengo una actividad de drawer menú,a la cual en el header lo edité para poder agrandarlo e incluirle campos de texto y botones, uno de esos botones en especifico el de registrarse lo quiero redireccionar a una actividad de registro,no es necesario que esa actividad de registro tenga el menu y toolbar, el tema es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo, Se hacer relaciones simples solo de activity empty a activity empty,me he desvelado tratando de resolverlo, no encuentro respuestas o de verdad es que soy muy muy cabeza dura.

el código de la actividad de registro:

```
package com.example.pcfactory1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
    }
}
```

el código del Main Activity:

```
package com.example.pcfactory1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.pcfactory1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home,R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

}
```

[image: imagen 1]
[image: imagen 2]
[image: imagen 3]
[image: imagen 5]
[image: imagen]
[image: imagen]

Comment: Si he entendido bien, quieres que al pulsar en el botón de Registrarse te redireccione a la Activity `Registro`. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? Entonces, tendrás que escuchar el click de ese botón y desde ahí llamar a la Activity `Registro`. Pero, si estas usando el Componente de Navegación de Android, ni siquiera necesitas una nueva Activity, `Registro` puede ser un `Fragment` y navegar hacia él cuando hagas click en el botón. Android está tendiendo a aplicaciones con una sola Activity y gestionar todo lo demás a través de Fragmentos.

Comment: Hola! es que necesitaba que esa pantalla se mostrara sola sin nada mas, he logrado resolverla, agregando un evento onClick al boton de registrarse le puse "siguiente" luego en el main activity dentro del public class, pero al final agregue lo siguiente:                                                                            public void siguiente(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: Yaaaap, es justo lo que te decía, necesitabas escuchar los clicks del botón y a partir de ahí decidir qué hacer. De todos modos, en vez de ir a un Activity, puedes navegar a un Fragment.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! investigare más acerca de los Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he logrado resolverla, agregando un evento onClick al boton de registrarse le puse "siguiente".

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_radius_musgo"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Registrarse"
        android:onClick="siguiente"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
```

luego en el MainActivity.class que es donde esta alojado el menu desplegable le puse esto al final dentro del public class principal.

aqui coloque el evento onClick creado "siguiente"

```
public void siguiente(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registro.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```